# Происхождение слова **плен**

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Интересна этимология слова **плен**, а так же хотелось бы узнать - имеется ли его связь с существительным **пелена**?

Answer (score 1):

Связи, судя по всему, нет:

[**Плен**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD):

Происходит от церк.-слав., от ст.-слав. плѣнъ (др.-греч. σκῦλα, αἰχμαλωλωσία; Супр.), от праслав. *pȇlnъ *неясного происхождения*, откуда также при исконнорусск. и укр. поло́н, белор. палон, сербохорв. пле̑н, плије̑н, словенск., чешск., словацк. plen, польск. plon.

См. также [**Поло́н**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-9965.htm):

род. п. -а, полони́ть, -ню́, укр. поло́н, полони́ти, блр. поло́н, др.-русск. полонъ, полонити, ст.-слав. плѣнъ λάφυρον (Супр.), плѣнити α ἰχμαλωτεύειν (Супр.), болг. плен (Младенов 428), сербохорв. пле̑н, пли̏jен "добыча", словен. рlе̣̑n "добыча, ограбление", чеш. рlеn "выручка, прибыль, урожай, добыча", слвц. рlеn "добыча, ограбление", польск. рlоn "жатва, урожай".

Праслав. ***реlnъ**, родственно лит. реl̃nаs "заслуга, заработок", реlnаũ, pelnýti "заслуживать", лтш. pèl̨n̨a "заслуга, прибыль", др.-инд. раṇаs м. "обещанная награда", páṇatē "скупает, закупает", греч. πωλέω "покупаю", д.-в.-н. fâli (из *fēli̯a-) "продажный", др.-исл. falr – то же, также др.-лит. peldù, peldė́ti "беречь, хранить" (Траутман, ВSW 213; Арr. Sprd. 392; И. Шмидт, Vok. 2, 78; Jеnаеr Lit. Zeit. 1874, стлб. 508; Фортунатов, ВВ 6, 217; AfslPh 4, 579; М.–Э. 3, 197, 198 и сл.; Хольтхаузен, Awn. Wb. 55; Торп 237; Гофман, Gr. Wb. 292; Ван-Вейк, ИОРЯС 20, 3, 38). Слово плен заимств. из цслав. Менее вероятно сравнение слав. слов с лат. pellis "шкура", гот. fill – то же, вопреки Брандту (РФВ 23, 292); см. об этих словах Вальде–Гофм. 2, 275 и сл.

А [**Пелена**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-9421.htm#:%7E:text=-%D0%BD.,%2C%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8C%22%2C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82.) от другого праславянского корня:

II пелена́
пе́лька, диал., новгор., боровск., псковск., "сшитое полотнище; пеленка" (Даль), укр. пелена́ "покров", др.-русск., ст.-слав. пелена σπάργανον (Клоц., Супр.), болг. пелена́, сербоß хорв. пелѐна, словен. реlеníса, рlеníса, чеш. pléna, рlеnа "пелена, оболочка", слвц. рlеnа.

Праслав. ***реlеnā**, ***реlnā** родственно лат. pellis (из *pelnis), греч. πέλας "кожа", πέλλΒ̄ς, вин. мн. "кожи", πελλο-ράφος "pellarius", д.-в.-н. fеl "шкура", греч. πέλμα "подошва (ноги, башмака)", англос. filmen "кожица, крайняя плоть", лит. plėnė "пленка, кожица" (Мейе, Ét. 444; Вальде–Гофм. 2, 275 и сл.; Траутман, ВSW 226; И. Шмидт, Vok. 2, 67; Клюге-Гётце 152 и сл.; Гофман, Gr. Wb. 260). Брандт (РФВ 23, 291) предполагает парадигму с вариантами разных ступеней. Произведение из тюрк. bēlänä "пеленка" (Менгес, Festschrift Čyževśkyj 190) сомнительно в фонетическом отношении.

Answer (score 0):

В санскрите:
pAlana - защита, охрана, забота.
phala(na) - добыча
В русском утрачены придыхательные согласные, потому многие разные корни стали звучать одинаково